How can I use mermaid in a extends page in gitbook?
All pages defines:
book.json
{
"plugins": \[

    "mermaid-gb3"

}
template/page.md
# {% block title %}Title{% endblock %}
{% block flowChart %} {% endblock %}
TestPage.md
{% extends "../template/page.md" %}
{% block title %}Test{% endblock %}
{% block flowChart %}
```mermaid
graph TD;
A-->B;
A-->C;
B-->D;
C-->D;
{% endblock %}
When I run 'gitbook serve' to preview, I don't see mermaid's flow chart, but a code block like this:
graph TD;
A-->B;
A-->C;
B-->D;
C-->D;

Can someone explain why, and How do I modify a document. Thank you very much
